# Group Dates in Google Sheet Filter

Tags: date, google-sheets, filter, slicers, group

is there any way I can group dates of a report in Google Sheets?
The difficulty that comes along is that this is a report that updates automatically every 4 hours (Salesforce connector).
When I add a slicer/filter option it shows me all the individual dates, but it would be great if I could somehow group them in the filter/slicer option only - without making changes to the live report from Salesforce.

Here is an example (Tab: Meetings): https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IVJECB6z7pNXl2xas6O6uixx7gZ5GY0wZaFkaad01dY/edit?usp=sharing

In the example I do not have a live report (obviously), but I am afraid creating a new column for date or even pivot table will be difficult as there will be new record lines added to the sheet through the salesforce connector as it updates automatically..

Comment: Just for clarification, the slicer option works for you & it just that it doesn't filter new data being added automatically on your sheet (via Salesforce connector), correct?

Comment: No the data will be automatically added to the sheet every 4 hours (just not in my example sheet I shared obviously because I cannot share real data). And once it's added the slicer will also show the new records...But I was wondering if I could group the dates with the slicer. I don't need all the individual dates to show but rather the months for example. I cannot add a new column to the report (I assume) because then I would have to do it for all new records once new ones are added to the sheet through the salesforce connector.

Comment: @IrvinJayG. Can you help out?